# How do I get this array of circles to appear within the boundary of a parallelogram?

Tags: random, geometry, p5.js

I understand how to get an array of circles to appear within a given square space, but how do I get them to appear within irregular shaped spaces. I have a parallelogram outlined that defines the boundaries of where I am trying to get the circles to appear, but no idea how to achieve this. Thanks!

Code from p5.js:

```
let circles = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1200, 1200);
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100,1);
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    x = random(400, 800);
    y = random(400, 800);
    d = 10;
    circles[i] = new circleClass(x, y, d);
  }
}


function draw() {
  
  background(35,13,90,1);
  
  noLoop();

  for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].show();
  }
  
  
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  quad(400,600,800,200,800,600,400,1000);
  
}



class circleClass {
  constructor(x, y, d) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
  }
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(27, 71, 73, 1);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.d);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an addition to MBo's answer above (+1).

The gist of is this section:

```
let x = v[0] + ax * t + bx * u
let y = v[1] + ay * t + by * u
```

This might look more familiar as the [equation of a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Geometric_interpretation).

In p5.js there's already a very useful [`lerp()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerp) function which takes two numbers and third parameter `t` between 0.0 and 1.0 and returns a number between the first two (e.g. if `t` is 0.5 the result will be 1/2 between the numbers, 0.25 would the 1/4 there and .75 would be 3/4, etc.).
Here's a basic example:

```js
let v1, v2, v3, v4;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  v1 = createVector(200, 300);
  v2 = createVector(400, 100);
  v3 = createVector(400, 300);
  v4 = createVector(200, 500);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  let t = map(constrain(mouseX, 0, width), 0, width, 0.0, 1.0);
  // interpolate each component, x,y between v1 and v2 using horizontal mouse movement
  let x = lerp(v1.x, v2.x, t);
  let y = lerp(v1.y, v2.y, t);
  // preview interpolated position
  circle(x, y, 10);
  
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  quad(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, v3.x, v3.y, v4.x, v4.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

We could use this directly, but it would get tedious to do 8 times (2 coordinates (x,y) for 4 points (quad)).

There's also very useful `p5.Vector` class in p5 with a [`p5.Vector.lerp()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/lerp) which can help easily interpolate between two points:

```js
let v1, v2, v3, v4;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  v1 = createVector(200, 300);
  v2 = createVector(400, 100);
  v3 = createVector(400, 300);
  v4 = createVector(200, 500);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  let t = map(constrain(mouseX, 0, width), 0, width, 0.0, 1.0);
  // interpolate each component, x,y between v1 and v2 using horizontal mouse movement
  let l = p5.Vector.lerp(v1, v2, t);
  // preview interpolated position
  circle(l.x, l.y, 10);
  
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  quad(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, v3.x, v3.y, v4.x, v4.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If we group interpolation between pairs of points using two different interpolation amounts into a reusable function we essentially implement a form of [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation):

```js
/**
* Bilinear interpolation: interpolates a point on a between two lines (defined by 4 points)
* @param xt: traversal on first axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
* @param yt: traversal on second axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
**/
function quadLerp(v1, v2, v3, v4, xt, yt){
    let v1to2 = p5.Vector.lerp(v1, v2, yt);
    let v3to4 = p5.Vector.lerp(v3, v4, yt);
    return p5.Vector.lerp(v1to2, v3to4, xt);
}
```

Demo:

```js
let v1, v2, v3, v4;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  v1 = createVector(200, 300);
  v2 = createVector(400, 100);
  v3 = createVector(400, 300);
  v4 = createVector(200, 500);
}

/**
* Bilinear interpolation: interpolates a point on a between two lines (defined by 4 points)
* @param xt: traversal on first axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
* @param yt: traversal on second axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
**/
function quadLerp(v1, v2, v3, v4, xt, yt){
    let v1to2 = p5.Vector.lerp(v1, v2, yt);
    let v3to4 = p5.Vector.lerp(v3, v4, yt);
    // text() is simply for debugging/visualisation purposed: not actually required
    text("v1to2", v1to2.x, v1to2.y);
    text("v3to4", v3to4.x, v3to4.y);
    return p5.Vector.lerp(v1to2, v3to4, xt);
}

function draw(){
  background(192, 255, 192);
  
  let u = map(constrain(mouseX, 0, width), 0, width, 0.0, 1.0);
  let v = map(constrain(mouseY, 0, height), 0, height, 0.0, 1.0);
  // vertex order (winding) is important
  let l = quadLerp(v1, v2, v4, v3, u, v);
  // preview interpolated position
  circle(l.x, l.y, 10);
  
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  quad(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, v3.x, v3.y, v4.x, v4.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Notice as the mouse moves across the whole sketch canvas the circle always stays within the bounds of the quad.

That's pretty much the solution: simply swap the mapped mouse coordinates for random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1200, 1200);
  background(192, 255, 192);
  
  let v1 = createVector(400, 600);
  let v2 = createVector(800, 200);
  let v3 = createVector(800, 600);
  let v4 = createVector(400, 1000);
  
  for (let i = 0 ; i < 500; i++) {
      let u = random();
      let v = random();
      // vertex order (winding) is important
      let l = quadLerp(v1, v2, v4, v3, u, v);
      circle(l.x, l.y, 10);
  }
  
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  quad(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, v3.x, v3.y, v4.x, v4.y);
}

/**
* Bilinear interpolation: interpolates a point on a between two lines (defined by 4 points)
* @param xt: traversal on first axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
* @param yt: traversal on second axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
**/
function quadLerp(v1, v2, v3, v4, xt, yt){
    let v1to2 = p5.Vector.lerp(v1, v2, yt);
    let v3to4 = p5.Vector.lerp(v3, v4, yt);
    return p5.Vector.lerp(v1to2, v3to4, xt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a variant closer to your code:

```js
let circles = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1200, 1200);
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100,1);
  background(35,13,90,1);
  
  let v1 = createVector(400, 600);
  let v2 = createVector(800, 200);
  let v3 = createVector(800, 600);
  let v4 = createVector(400, 1000);
  
  for (let i = 0 ; i < 500; i++) {
      let u = random();
      let v = random();
      // vertex order (winding) is important
      let l = quadLerp(v1, v2, v4, v3, u, v);
      circles[i] = new Circle(l.x, l.y, 10);
      circles[i].show();
  }
  
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  quad(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, v3.x, v3.y, v4.x, v4.y);
}

/**
* Bilinear interpolation: interpolates a point on a between two lines (defined by 4 points)
* @param xt: traversal on first axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
* @param yt: traversal on second axis (0.0 -> 1.0)
**/
function quadLerp(v1, v2, v3, v4, xt, yt){
    let v1to2 = p5.Vector.lerp(v1, v2, yt);
    let v3to4 = p5.Vector.lerp(v3, v4, yt);
    return p5.Vector.lerp(v1to2, v3to4, xt);
}

class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, d) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
  }
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(27, 71, 73, 1);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.d);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I've made a couple of tweaks:

- renamed `circleClass` to simply `Circle` keeping the naming convention of a title case class name. I've removed the `Class` part to avoid potential confusion when instantiating circles (e.g. `new circleClass()`)
- I've removed `draw()`, hence removing the need for `noLoop();`
- the `circles` array is sort of redundant too in this basic example, but could useful in a more detailed, animated version of this sketch.

Take you time to read/tweak/break/fix the code above.
Understanding the basics will save you so much time on the long run.
It's may appear counter intuitive, but sometimes slowing down helps you speed up. Have fun!

Comment: This answer is genuinely incredible. Thank you so much for taking the time to write out the solution in such detail, showing all your workings, and explaining all the logic. This has been incredibly helpful!

Comment: Glad it helps and happy to hear the detailed explanations help.  Bare in mind, while my version hopefully is easy to understand it is not the most efficient (for example, for each point creates 3 p5.Vector instances. (e.g. if you run this in interactively in `draw()` it doesn't use memory efficiently. Notice there's a p5.js snippet now at the bottom of MBo's answer: that is more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you want to generate small circles in random positions inside parallelogram.

Take two vectors of parallelogram sides, and generate random points using linear combination of these vectors:

```
ax = v[1].x - v[0].x  (800-400 for your quad)
ay = v[1].y - v[0].y  (200-600 for your quad)
bx = v[2].x - v[0].x   (and so on)
by = v[2].y - v[0].y

t = random(0..1)
u = random(0..1)
x = v[0].x + ax * t + bx * u
y = v[0].y + ay * t + by * u
```

where `v[]` is array of parallelogram vertices

```
let v = [400,600,800,200,800,600,400,1000]
let ax = v[2] - v[0]
let ay = v[3] - v[1]
let bx = v[4] - v[0]
let by = v[5] - v[0]

for loop {
    let t = Math.random()
    let u = Math.random()
    let x = v[0] + ax * t + bx * u
    let y = v[1] + ay * t + by * u
    set circle center in x, y
```

Here's a p5.js version:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(255);
  
  let v = [200, 300,   // top left     array indices: [x=0, y=1]
           400, 100,   // top right    array indices: [x=2, y=3]
           400, 300,   // bottom right array indices: [x=4, y=5]
           200, 500];  // bottom left  array indices: [x=6, y=7]
  
  // top right - top left
  let ax = v[2] - v[0];
  let ay = v[3] - v[1];
  // bottom left - top left
  let bx = v[6] - v[0];
  let by = v[7] - v[1];

  for(let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      let t = random(); // interpolation amount on 1 axis
      let u = random(); // interpolation amount on the other
      // offset by top left point (v[0], v[1])
      // interpolate along top left to top right (imagine X axis aligned with parallelogram sides)
      // and top left to bottom left (imagine Y axis aligned with parallelogram sides)
      let x = v[0] + (ax * t + bx * u);
      let y = v[1] + (ay * t + by * u);
      // render point
      circle(x, y, 10);
  }
  
  noFill();
  // pass the v array as arguments using the spread operator
  quad(...v);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! are you able to show me how this would fit into the code I provided?

Comment: @astromango it's worth trying to understand the logic of the snippet above: there's a lot more to learn this way. Here are a few pointers: As MBo mentioned, "v[] is array of parallelogram vertices" so start with that, using your quad coordinates(`400,600,800,200,800,600,400,1000`). (e.g. `v = [{x:400, y:600},{x:800,y:200},...` and so on). In p5 a random between 0 and 1 is `random(0, 1)`. once you have your x,y coordinates you can use them for your circle instances. There may be a fun challenge to tackle: taking the circle diameter into account. Take you time, you got this!

Comment: @astromango I am not strong in js, so just pseudocode

Comment: thanks @GeorgeProfenza. I will give this a go. I've spend about an hour on it so far with no luck, I think I have quite a bit of learning to go on the basics before tackling this stuff!

Comment: @astromango I've posted a step-by-step detailed solution

Comment: @George Profenza I really surprised what might be unclear in my pseudocode :(

Comment: @MBo I think the pseudocode is great! I've made minor tweaks to coordinates (since quad vertices is originally in clock-wise order) and shrunk coordinates by half so it's easier to see when running the snippet. I've added some comments based on how understood your pseudo-code: If I've misunderstood something or you have improvements feel free to edit of course. Your method is simpler and more memory efficient than mine. In my answer I was hoping to break down some concepts and thought using vectors with x,y component might be easier to follow.

Comment: @George Profenza All is right. I believe that in my case pseudocode is better than low-quality attempt of making valid JS code ;)